# insert value between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table made from with a query.

```
m_id s_s                    s_e                 a_s_t
101  2019-12-23 13:08:49  2019-12-23 13:13:12   NS
101  2019-12-23 13:14:35  2019-12-23 13:14:56   MS
```

Desired table

```
m_id s_s                    s_e                 a_s_t
101  2019-12-23 13:08:49  2019-12-23 13:13:12   NS
**101  2019-12-23 13:13:12  2019-12-23 13:14:35   UP**
101  2019-12-23 13:14:35  2019-12-23 13:14:56   MS
```

How can i insert the UP between NS and MS (a_s_t column).

The UP s_s should be the s_s of the previous row and the UP s_e the s_s of the next row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with firstq as (
    select m_id ,s_s,s_e,a_s_t, lead(s_s,1) over (partition by m_id order by s_s) next_s_s
    from table_x)
select m_id,s_s,s_e,a_s_t
from firstq
union all
select m_id, s_e,next_s_s,'UP'
from firstq
where next_s_s is not null
order by m_id, s_s
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment.

I need the s_e of the previous record and the s_s of the next record.

With your query i only get the s_s of the next record, but not the s_e of the previous one right?

Comment: Did you try the query to see what you get, and if fits your requirements?

Comment: There is a character set mismatch error im getting.

Comment: Fixed the character set mismatch with cast ('UP' as nvarchar2(100))

Comment: Well, I had no way of figuring out your column was an nvarchar2, no?

Comment: yes, that is correct. But your query worked. Just added the cast function to it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
insert into t (m_id, s_s, s_e, a_s_t)
    select m_id, min(s_e), max(s_s), 'UP'
    from t
    group by m_id;
```

This does not insert the new row "between" the other two rows, because that does not make sense.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

It does insert a row with the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

It means you need to fill the gap.

Use following query:

```
Insert into your_table
Select m_id, s_e, lss, 'UP' from
(Select t.*, 
        lead(s_s) over (partition by m_id order by s_s) as lss
  From your_table t)
Where s_e <> lss
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks, i will check it try it

Comment: in the where statement i cannot select the LSS. i tried with t.lss and without.

Comment: why not? You will be able to use it in the WHERE clause. share your query that you are trying

Comment: sorry maybe i was not clear in my explenation. I have build my own query to get the result in my question.

Im not trying to insert values into an existing table.